# github how to clone an organization's private repository inside a container

Tags: github

I am writing a docker container. it should clone a git repository. the repository is under an organization and private. How do i accomplish this? I do not want to copy ssh keys.

The following solution in github documentation does not work because you will be prompted to input your username and password which i can't do when running inside the container.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

These commands did not help either. i may have messed the command:

```
$ git clone https://OrganizationName:personal-access-token@github.com/OrganizationName/RepoName.git
Cloning into 'XXX'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/OrganizationName/RepoName.git/' not found


$ git clone https://my-github-username:personal-access-token@github.com/OrganizationName/RepoName.git
Cloning into 'XXXX'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/OrganizationName/RepoName.git/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this.  One is to mount your existing SSH keys inside the container with the `-v` option, which will work only if they keys don't have a passphrase.  This can be your SSH key or a deploy key for that repository.

The other is to pass a token in through an environment variable using the `-e` option and [the technique specified in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment), which should be run in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN git config --global credential.helper \
    '!f() { echo username=username; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f'
```

That assumes your username is `username` and the environment variable with the token is `GIT_TOKEN`.

Note that in either case, if your organization uses SSO, you'll need to enable the key or the token for SSO in the settings interface.

You should not put the token into the URL because this will bake it into the container and then you'll expose your credentials every time you provide the container to others.  This is true even when you're not using a container because Git stores URLs in plaintext on disk, which means it's easy to expose accidentally.

Comment: so i should use the RUN instruction to execute the command above and then do a git clone? can you please provide the full example how it should look like? thanks!

Comment: I've updated it to show the expected invocation in a Dockerfile.  You do the clone after setting this value.